# Select All checkbox should not select disabled checkbox records angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Have datatable and if check select all checkbox, need to select which are in enabled checkbox records and avoid disabled records. I tried this below code, I'm unable to restrict disabled record selection.

```
  checkuncheckall() {
    const totalChecked = this.persons.filter(f => f.checked).length;
    const target = totalChecked !== this.persons.length;
    this.persons.forEach(f => (f.checked = target));
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

html code:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" [disabled]="person.firstName === 'Superman'" class="checkboxCls" [value]="person.checked" [checked]="person.checked" name="id" (change)="person.checked = !person.checked"></td>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-records-only-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

```js
checkuncheckall() {
    //First filter enabled checkbox
    const filteredCheckboxes = this.persons.filter(f => f.firstName !== "Superman");
    const totalChecked = filteredCheckboxes.filter(f => f.checked).length;
    const target = totalChecked !== filteredCheckboxes.length;
    filteredCheckboxesforEach(f => f.checked = target);
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```